# Let $A = \left\{ P_\Delta (\lambda ):\| \Delta_j \| \le \varepsilon w_j ,j = 0,1,2,\ldots,m \right\}$.What is boundary of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose

- $P_\Delta(\lambda ) = (A_m + \Delta_m) \lambda ^m + \cdots + (A_1 + \Delta _1)\lambda ^1 + (A_0 + \Delta _0)$  is a matrix polynomial,  and $\lambda $ is a complex variable.
- $A_j,\Delta _j \in C^{n \times n},\quad (j = 0,1,2,\ldots,m)$
- $w_j \ge 0,(j = 0,1,\ldots,m)$ and $w_0>0$.
- $A = \left\{ P_\Delta(\lambda ):\left\| \Delta_j \right\| \le \varepsilon w_j, j = 0,1,2,\ldots,m \right\}$
- $\| \cdot \|$ is  subordinate matrix norm, and $\partial A$ is boundary of $A$.

In this case, can we prove;
$\partial A = \{ P_\Delta (\lambda ):\|\Delta_j\| \le \varepsilon w_j$ for each $j $, and equality holds for at least one $j$ $\}$ =$S$?

If no,  which Counterexample can be violated?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, and we can prove that this is the case.  In reference to your earlier question regarding the interior, note that with the *usual* notion of the interior, we have
$$
\operatorname{int}(A) = \overline{A} \setminus \partial A
$$
consider what this means in the case that $w_j = 0$ for some $j$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - I shall be grateful, If you more guide me.

Comment: So you're just looking for a proof of the form of $\partial A$ using the definition of $A$, is that right?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - If ${P_\Delta }({\lambda _0}) \in \partial A$, and $U$ be neighborhood near ${P_\Delta }({\lambda _0})$, in this space. What is $U$?

Comment: The open ball of radius $\delta$ about $P^{(0)}_{\Delta}(\lambda)$(which is usually the "neighborhood" that people use) is
$$
\{P_{\Delta}(\lambda): \|\Delta_j - \Delta_j^{(0)}\| < \delta \text{ for all } j \}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Let $P_\Delta ^0(\lambda ) \in S$ and $B(P_\Delta ^0(\lambda ),\varepsilon )$ be the open ball of radius $\varepsilon $ about $P_\Delta ^0(\lambda )$. Which $P_\Delta ^{}(\lambda )$ belongs to $B(P_\Delta ^0(\lambda ),\varepsilon ) \cap A$? and which $P_\Delta ^{}(\lambda )$ belongs to $B(P_\Delta ^0(\lambda ),\varepsilon ) \cap A^c$?

Comment: Did you mean $A$ instead of $S$? Or is $S = \partial A$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - If  $S = \{ P_\Delta (\lambda ):\|\Delta_j\| \le \varepsilon w_j$ for each $j $, and equality holds for at least one $j$ $\}$ then $\partial A\mathop  = \limits^? S$.